I am trying to copy files between network drives using VBA in excel,
I am trying to copy files between folders using VBA in excel,using filesystemobject.CopyFolder but only on C: drive, but can't do it across network drives
I have tried using this procedure
Sub aatest() 'Richards file copy procedure
    

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "\\swv082fs\Data\test"
    ToPath = "C:\Users\rilindley\Data"


    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

End Sub


"can't do it" - what exactly happens when you try?

Your approach seems to be generally sound, I think you just need to add some error checking to your code. The issue you're encountering is likely related to network permissions or the way the network path is being accessed:

Make sure you have read/write permissions for both FromPath and ToPath.
Sometimes, using WScript.Shell can bypass certain permission issues with network paths.

Try using the WScript.Shell approach, or handle errors more gracefully:
Sub CopyNetworkFolder()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "\\swv082fs\Data\test\"
    ToPath = "C:\Users\rilindley\Data\"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Check if source folder exists
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) Then
        MsgBox "Source folder doesn't exist: " & FromPath, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check if destination folder exists, create if it doesn't
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder ToPath
    End If

    ' Copy the folder
    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "Folder copied successfully!", vbInformation

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub

